# Como retornar si un usuario especifico existe en una tabla e indicar que tabla es?

Tags: sql, oracle

Les cuento, tengo una tabla principal TIENDAS que esta ligado a una tabla USUARIOS que cada usuario tiene su ID_USUARIO.

Tengo 3 tablas mas que son hijas de tabla TIENDAS que serian los DEPARTAMENTOS (tabla usuarios y departamentos comparten los id usuario).

DEPARTAMENTO 1
DEPARTAMENTO 2
DEPARTAMENTO 3

Necesito saber si una persona existe en X departamento mediante su ID_USUARIO, y si no existe no traerla en el resultado.

Ejemplo:

Tenemos a Juan, Carlos y José. Juan y Jose pertenecen al departamento 1, y Carlos al departamento 3. Ninguno pertenece al departamento 2.

Necesitaria que me retorne algo asi:

Juan - Departamento1
Jose - Departamento 1
Carlos - Departamento 3

El problema de esto, es que no tengo una tabla descriptiva de los departamentos, entonces tendre que dar a conocer el departamento solamente si reconoce el ID del usuario en la tabla del departamento.

Imagino quizas con algun decode. Realmente no sé.

Como podria realizar esa consulta amigos?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Al no ver tu código solo se me ocurre algo así en mysql.

SELECT * FROM tiendas LEFT JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id_tienda = tiendas.id_dienda LEFT JOIN departamento_1 ON departamento_1.id_tienda = tiendas.id_tienda WHERE usuarios.id_usuario = "1";

Comment: Creo que necesitas rediseñar tu base de datos para tener una sola tabla de departamentos. Así puedes ligar los usuarios a departamentos y los departamentos a tiendas. De otro modo, será una pesadilla agregar departamentos más adelante.